# Randomly failed because of JSON::ParserError : 822: unexpected token

Tags: json, ruby

I have a REST POST API that receives json data and validates parameters. In the production environment, the API sometimes raises an exception:

```
JSON::ParserError : 822: unexpected token at ...
```

The stack trace is like:

```
> .../gems/ruby-2.2.10/gems/json-1.8.6/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
> .../gems/ruby-2.2.10/gems/json-1.8.6/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
> .../gems/ruby-2.2.10/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/json/decoding.rb:26:in `decode'
```

It seems that the error occurs randomly; I cannot find any pattern.

When I try the same code with the dumped data, there is no parsing error.

I thought the error is due to running in concurrent, but I tried it in local with 1000 concurrent requests, which are far more than in the production environment, and it still works without any error.

I appreciate to throw some light.

What does the `822` mean in the error message? It does not seem to be the character position in the json data.

Comment: `JSON::ParserError : 822: unexpected token` means there was a request sent to the server that did not include valid JSON. Are you sure that your log includes the sent data? I guess - because Rails raises that error before even calling the controller - that you will not be able to see the data that was to the application in your log file.

Comment: The input actually is a zipped data, so it is logged in the error handling.

Comment: Can you add the code that unzips and converts to JSON?